# How to add a link to .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

History.pushState and window.onpopstate are used in this [demo](http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/popstate_2019/). 
You can go back and forward with the browser buttons.
But after after refreshing the page e.g 'selected=box-2' is error 404.

Is it possible to add these links to .htaccess?

**1. js file**

```
let boxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('box'));

function selectBox (id) {
    boxes.forEach(b => {
        b.classList.toggle('selected', b.id === id);
    });
}

boxes.forEach(b => {
    let id = b.id;
    b.addEventListener('click', e => {
        history.pushState({id}, `Selected: ${id}`, `./selected=${id}`)
        selectBox(id);
    });
});

window.addEventListener('popstate', e => {
    selectBox(e.state.id);
});

history.replaceState({id: null}, 'Default state', './');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add these links to .htaccess"? Such dynamic configuration files do a lot of stuff, so what is it you actually want? If you want to rewrite or redirect requests to the http server, then please give clear URLs you want to rewrite, not some javascript code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do not know well on .htaccess, "what is it you actually want?" -  I think you have already answered my question - this is javascript:)  and probably a virtual link can not be assigned to htaccess.

Comment: Real Project - [link](http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/testsite1/public/), the same problem, when I go to the product detail, I can not go back. 404 error.

Comment: Again: it is unclear what you mean by "assign" here. I suggest you explain what you want to do, not _how you might be able to_ do it.